# Domain & Sub domain - On Page Optimization

Tags: cross-domain, robots.txt

I have website

Main domain www.domain.com

Sub Domains

1. www.movie.tollywood.domain.com www.movie.hollywood.domain.com
   www.songs.hollywood.domain.com

I don't want to crawl and index the subdomains in all search engine.

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: I Know the robots.txt but how to restrict the crawl & Index.                                                     Useragent *                                                                                                                  Diallow: /                                                                                                                                        This is correct or Wrong

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate robots.txt file for each sub domain which will go into the root of those sub domains.

And to stop ALL search engines from crawling them you would add the following to each of them...

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The above example is a wildcard as noted by the *, this means it targets all search engines.

If you only want to target Googlebot then you would add the following...

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
```